# Como construir um XML completo em T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, xml, tsql

Estou elaborando uma procedure que retorna um campo em XML, até aí nada mal. O problema surge quando eu tenho dados iniciais vindo de uma consulta e dados intermediários vindo de uma outra consulta.

Tentei solucionar com concatenação de string e depois converter para XML, mas como preciso repetir um processo através de um cursor, não sei como fazer essa concatenação.

```
DECLARE @XML_RETORNO XML;
SET @XML_RETORNO = '<root>'
+'<nome>Marcelo</nome>'
+'<itens>'
-- Quero começar um cursor aqui
+'<item tipo="carro">Fusca</item>'
+'<item tipo="carro">Gol</item>'
+'<item tipo="moto">CG-150</item>'
-- Termino do cursor
+'</itens>'
+'</root>';

SELECT CAST(@XML_RETORNO AS XML)
```

### Editado

Este exemplo é apenas uma ilustração do que preciso. Na verdade a instrução SQL que estou montando é chamada por uma **Trigger** e precisa reunir dados para preencher um **campo XML de uma outra tabela**. O maior problema é que só conheço uma forma de montar um XML pelo T-SQL, essa forma é concatenando strings e transformando posteriormente em XML.

Comment: Poste seu código (a parte pertinente)!

Comment: Editei o código, ele é um exemplo mais fácil de compreender, na verdade o código é bem mais extenso.

Comment: Você chegou a tentar [`FOR XML...`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com base no exemplo da pergunta, fiz um código que transforma um resultado num XML semelhante:

```sql
SELECT 
(
SELECT
  nome,
  (
  SELECT 
    tipo AS 'item/@tipo',
    descricao as 'item'
    FROM item
    WHERE item.pessoa = pessoa.id
    ORDER BY descricao
    FOR XML PATH(''), Type
  ) as 'itens'
FROM pessoa
ORDER BY nome
FOR XML PATH('pessoa'), Type
)
FOR XML PATH('root')
```

### [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b461c/13)

O resultado é:

```xml
<root>
    <pessoa>
        <nome>Luiz</nome>
        <itens>
            <item tipo="moto">CG-150</item>
            <item tipo="carro">Uno</item>
        </itens>
    </pessoa>
    <pessoa>
        <nome>Marcelo</nome>
        <itens>
            <item tipo="carro">Fusca</item>
            <item tipo="carro">Gol</item>
        </itens>
    </pessoa>
</root>
```

Para obter o resultado dentro de uma *trigger*, basta você aplicar a *query* nas "tabelas" `INSERTED` e `DELETED` e armazenar o valor em uma variável. Então fica fácil colocar o valor em qualquer outro campo de tabela!

Answer (score 2):

A maneira mais performática de fazer isso é usando a declaração `FOR XML('SuaTagRaiz')`. Não sei como é sua tabela, mas suponha uma tabela de estados (no meu sistema, `States`). A sentença assim:

```
SELECT * 
FROM States
FOR XML PATH('State'), ROOT('States')
```

Gera um XML assim:

```
<States>
  <State>
    <StateID>1</StateID>
    <CountryID>1</CountryID>
    <Name>Paraná</Name>
  </State>
  <State>
    <StateID>2</StateID>
    <CountryID>1</CountryID>
    <Name>Acre</Name>
  </State>
  <State>
    <StateID>3</StateID>
    <CountryID>1</CountryID>
    <Name>Alagoas</Name>
  </State>
  <State>
    <StateID>4</StateID>
    <CountryID>1</CountryID>
    <Name>Amapá</Name>
  </State>
  <State>
    <StateID>5</StateID>
    <CountryID>1</CountryID>
    <Name>Amazonas</Name>
  </State>
  <State>
    <StateID>6</StateID>
    <CountryID>1</CountryID>
    <Name>Bahia</Name>
  </State>
  <State>
    <StateID>7</StateID>
    <CountryID>1</CountryID>
    <Name>Ceará</Name>
  </State>
  <State>
    <StateID>8</StateID>
    <CountryID>1</CountryID>
    <Name>Distrito Federal</Name>
  </State>
  <State>
    <StateID>9</StateID>
    <CountryID>1</CountryID>
    <Name>Espírito Santo</Name>
  </State>
  <State>
    <StateID>10</StateID>
    <CountryID>1</CountryID>
    <Name>Goiás</Name>
  </State>
  <State>
    <StateID>11</StateID>
    <CountryID>1</CountryID>
    <Name>Maranhão</Name>
  </State>
  <State>
    <StateID>12</StateID>
    <CountryID>1</CountryID>
    <Name>Mato Grosso</Name>
  </State>
  <State>
    <StateID>13</StateID>
    <CountryID>1</CountryID>
    <Name>Mato Grosso do Sul</Name>
  </State>
  <State>
    <StateID>14</StateID>
    <CountryID>1</CountryID>
    <Name>Minas Gerais</Name>
  </State>
  <State>
    <StateID>15</StateID>
    <CountryID>1</CountryID>
    <Name>Pará</Name>
  </State>
  <State>
    <StateID>16</StateID>
    <CountryID>1</CountryID>
    <Name>Paraíba</Name>
  </State>
  <State>
    <StateID>17</StateID>
    <CountryID>1</CountryID>
    <Name>Pernambuco</Name>
  </State>
  <State>
    <StateID>18</StateID>
    <CountryID>1</CountryID>
    <Name>Piauí</Name>
  </State>
  <State>
    <StateID>19</StateID>
    <CountryID>1</CountryID>
    <Name>Rio de Janeiro</Name>
  </State>
  <State>
    <StateID>20</StateID>
    <CountryID>1</CountryID>
    <Name>Rio Grande do Norte</Name>
  </State>
  <State>
    <StateID>21</StateID>
    <CountryID>1</CountryID>
    <Name>Rio Grande do Sul</Name>
  </State>
  <State>
    <StateID>22</StateID>
    <CountryID>1</CountryID>
    <Name>Rondônia</Name>
  </State>
  <State>
    <StateID>23</StateID>
    <CountryID>1</CountryID>
    <Name>Roraima</Name>
  </State>
  <State>
    <StateID>24</StateID>
    <CountryID>1</CountryID>
    <Name>Santa Catarina</Name>
  </State>
  <State>
    <StateID>25</StateID>
    <CountryID>1</CountryID>
    <Name>São Paulo</Name>
  </State>
  <State>
    <StateID>26</StateID>
    <CountryID>1</CountryID>
    <Name>Sergipe</Name>
  </State>
  <State>
    <StateID>27</StateID>
    <CountryID>1</CountryID>
    <Name>Tocantins</Name>
  </State>
</States>
```

Comment: Acho que não expliquei o suficiente, vou dar mais uma editada.